# Open Jquery Accordion Menu from exteral link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems getting my jquery accordion side menu to open up to the correct when I click a link from my top menu.  Sorry I switched up my code.    Here are my pages:

HERE IS MY JS for side nav :

```
function initMenu() {
$('#nav ul').hide();
/*$('#nav ul:first').show();*/
$('#nav li a').click(
function() {
  var checkElement = $(this).next();
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    return true;
    }
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('#nav ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    return false;
     }
   }
 );
}
$(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

My UL LIST for side nav

```
<ul id="nav"> 
 <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>    
 <ul>      
<li><a href="#">test1</a></li>      
<li><a href="#">test2</a></li>      
<li><a href="#">test3</a></li>  
 </ul>  
</li> 
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a>  
  <ul>     
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>  
  </ul> 
</li>  
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a>  
   <ul>      
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
   <li><a href="test1.shtml">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
  </ul> 
</li>  
<li><a href="#">Item 4</a>    
<ul>     
 <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>    
 <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li> 
</ul>  
</li>
</ul>
```

The page I want to make active

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('search', '1', {language: 'en', style: google.loader.themes.V2_DEFAULT});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
var customSearchOptions = {};
customSearchOptions['overlayResults'] = true;
var customSearchControl =   new       google.search.CustomSearchControl('008189712368144530774:cd8hgx1d4hk',   customSearchOptions);
customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
}, true);

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="topbox">
     <div id="topnav"><!--#include file="topnav.html" --></div>
     <div id='cse'>Loading</div>
</div>
<div id="leftcol">
    <div id="Topleft"><!--#include file="topleftphoto.html" --></div>
    <div id="SideNav"><!--#include file="sidenavdistrict.html" --></div>
</div>
<div id="rightcol">
    <div id="TopRight">Content for  id "topright" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="Body">Content for  id "body" Goes Here</div>
</div>
<div id="Footer">Content for  id "footer" Goes Here</div>
 </div>
```

any thoughts on how to fix this would be great.  Im just learning how to use this so if you do help please be specific on where things should go.  You can check out live site at www.rsd17.org/test/test/untitled1.shtml Thanks

Comment: Sorry could you be a little more specific on what you want to do? You want the accordion to open when you click a link on the top menu?

Comment: I have a top spry nav bar, and a jquery accordion side nav bar.  When I click on a link from the top spry bar I want it to expand the correct bar on the accordion to reflect the correct active page.  Hopefully that clears it up alittle bit.

Comment: anyone of you javascript guru's have any thoughts with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry been busy couldn't answer earlier.

You could do that this way:

Add ids to both navs:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="topbox">
        <div id="topnav"><ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
  <li  id="dis"><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">DISTRICT</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="test1.shtml">Item 1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li  id="sch"><a href="#">SCHOOLS</a></li>
  <li  id="stu"><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">STUDENTS</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3.1</a>      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="sta"><a href="#">STAFF</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">PARENTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">COMMUNITY</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CALENDAR</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">QUICKLINKS</a></li>
</ul>

( ... )

<ul id="nav"> 
 <li ><a href="#">Item 1</a>    
  <ul id="i1">      
    <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>      
    <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>      
    <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>  
  </ul>  
</li> 
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>  
      <ul  id="i2">     
       <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>  
      </ul> 
    </li>  
    <li><a href="test1.shtml" id="test1">Item 3</a>  
       <ul id="i3">      
       <li><a href="#" >Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
      </ul> 
   </li>  
   <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>    
    <ul id="i4">     
     <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>    
     <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li> 
   </ul>  
   </li>
  </ul>
```

And use this javascript:

```
<script>
            var ul = document.getElementById('topnav');
            ul.onclick = function(event) {                  
                switch (event.target.parentNode.id){
                    case "dis" : $('#nav ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                                $('#i1').slideDown('normal');
                                break;

                    case "sch" : $('#nav ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                                $('#i2').slideDown('normal');                               
                                break;

                    case "stu" : $('#nav ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                                $('#i3').slideDown('normal');
                                break;

                    case "sta" : $('#nav ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                                $('#i4').slideDown('normal');
                                break;
                }

            };
</script>
```

This has to be after `<script type='text/javascript' src='nav.js'></script>`

I tried with your page and with every click on the top menu opens the corresponding item on the side menu. I think that's what you want. However doing this way you have to add new code for each item on the switch. Try it out ;)

EDIT --------------------------------------------------

I will suppose the name of the page number will open the corresponding item. (district1 will open item 1, district2 will open item 2, schools1 will open item 1, etc)

Also always use the ids i1, i2, i3... for the side menu, you don't need i6, i7, etc like you have on students.

If you will always change page you don't need the previous code, just this.

```
$('#body').ready(function(){
                var URL = location.pathname;

                for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){ // 4 = number of items, if you add more increase it
                    if(URL.indexOf(i) != -1){
                        $('#nav ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                        $('#i'+i).slideDown('normal');
                    }
                }
            });
```

Don't forget this has to be after  `<script type='text/javascript' src='nav.js'></script>`.

Comment: Great thanks, I'll try this out tomorrow.  The top nav buttons each are going to have their own side nav, so I'm going to be making 8 side navs.  So under district right now I have 3 submenus say.  say the first submenu should open item 1, second submenu should open item 2, etc.  is the code above going to be the same to do that?

Comment: Yes. The above code right makes the DISTRICT opens side Item 1, SCHOOLS opens side Item 2, STUDENTS opens side Item 3 and STAFF opens side Item 4. If you want 8 you have to add to the switch clause, just add cases like:
case "[nav id]" : $('#nav ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                                $('#[side id]').slideDown('normal');
                                break;   I can help you do that if you need.

Comment: great the single one works great, now im trying to get the other links working correctly with your switch clause.  if you want to check out the site again.  www.rsd17.org/test/test/untitled1.shtml i added links to the item 1,2,3, but now the nav doesn't slide open.  i added case "[topnav]" : $('#nav ul:visible').slideUp('normal');$('[sidenavtest]').slideDown('normal');break; to the district one and and did something like that for the sidenavestudents.  any thoughts?

Comment: With the  case "[topnav]" : $('#nav ul:visible').slideUp('normal');$('[sidenavtest]').slideDown('normal');break;  i meant that you have to replace the [topnav] with the top menu id that you want. And [sidenavtest] with the id of the side menu what you want. It doesn't slide open because you are moving to a different page. When you do that the javascript resets, when you click Item 1.1 on the district you want that item 1 opens on the side menu?

Comment: Ah I didn't know you wanted to change the page, there's no way to pass variable from a page to another using javascript, so each time you change the page there's no way of knowing which one should be open using javascript. Two ways of doing that: using an iframe or passing the variable on the URL. Also you could see the page's name and open the side menu accordingly. I actually prefer the last since you don't need to worry if the user messes with the GET parameters. You will need to update the code if you change the page name though. I will edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: I think I have it all set now.  Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: You should set the answer as correct and the question answered. You're welcome, glad I could help :)

Comment: quick question for you hugo.  I have added some items to the submenus finally on the side nav and when I click on them it closes and reopens the menu.  Is there a way to have the menu stay open when you click on the submenus?  example if you go to www.rsd17.org/test/test/untitled1.shtml, then click on board of education, and the first two submenus I added dummy links to for testing.  when you click on them it closes and reopens the correct nav.  but can we have it if you click on things on the submenu it stays open.  Have it so only the main buttons on the side nav can open can close things.

Comment: Hey! Try adding in the if this if((URL.indexOf(i) != -1) && (!$('#i'+i).is(':visible')). Should work, if not I will try to see it more carefully. Pretty CSS btw ;)

Comment: Also Hugo I don't know if you could look at the code and see if it would be easy to make a link active so I can go in css to change the css.

Comment: I think I figured out where that line goes, just add it to the old one.  but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.